# Cannot run Oberon program in xds

Tags: oberon

I am trying to run Hello World program in Oberon in XDS compiler.

I can compile the hello.ob2 file, I can make hello.ob2, however when I press run it says that there is no hello.exe file.

I found at XDS manual that we have to do linking. It is not clear how to link it in GUI, but it is possible to do it via command line: xlink /sys=c /name=hello hello.obj d:\xds\lib\x86\libxds.lib.

Well, I did this using git bash, however the response is Error(0): unable to open sys=c.obj

I read at manual also that "The compiler, when invoked in the PROJECT mode, may automatically produce a response file and invoke the link". So, I assumed that Project mode means creating a new project.

So, I create a new project. And now, when I run the project it says:"No modules are in the project".

Can somebody tell me how I can run this project?

Or may be you can recommend me other compiler with simple and clear documentation?

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is a late response, but still..

Add a <* +MAIN *> before your MODULE keyword. Build using xc =m hello.ob2